# Why does C# use structs instead of classes for internal KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct, equality

I was under the impression structs should be used for:

- short-lived values (usually survives for entire object life)
- size under 16 bytes (usually string keys which can easily exceed such

Also, aren't these being heap-allocated anyway because you obviously can't store all of these large key-value nodes on the stack? There might even be some boxing costs.

The reason why I ask is because I'm implementing a data structure as well that uses similar constructs and I noticed many speed gains from using classes instead of structs and was wondering what Microsoft's rationale was for doing this, other than perhaps immutability.

But even then, it might be faster to just return a copied KeyValueNode when that happens, no?

Source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/keyvaluepair.cs,8585965bb176a426

Comment: The statement "value types go on the stack" is not a true statement.  You seem to think that it is, given your question, but it's not true at all.  The only difference between a value type and a reference type is that whenever you use an instance of that type, a value type is the actual value, and for a reference type the value is just a reference to where the actual value is.  Everything else follows from that basic premise.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a structure of any size that is small enough not to kill the stack will *always* be cheaper than creating a class object *of that same size*.  Passing any size of structure to a method which expects a reference type will *always* be more expensive than passing a heap-object reference.  Accessing a member of a structure held in an array will generally be cheaper than accessing a member of a class object identified to by a reference stored held in an array.  Copying a large structure is more expensive than copying a small structure or a heap-object reference, but unless a structure is copied more than twice, the cost of such copying will not exceed the extra cost associated with creating a class object of that size; unless an object is really big, it would need to be copied many times before the extra copy cost exceeded the savings in class-object-construction overhead.

If `Dictionary` were to maintain an array of references key-value-pair objects, the cost of having its enumerator return references to items in that array would be slightly less than the cost of having it return a copy of items from an array holding key-value-pair structures.  Further, when a dictionary is expanded, the cost of copying references to key-value objects would be slightly less than the cost of copying key-value-pair structures.  The general cost of adding items to the dictionary would be increased, however, as would the cost of retrieving values (as opposed to key-value pairs) from it.  For most common use cases of the dictionary, using a key-value-pair object would end up being more expensive than using a structure.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reasons you have given, another important reason why you might use structs is that two structs that have the same value are treated as being equal when used with the `Equals()` method **if the equals method is not overriden** because they are value types, much like two variables of type `int` will be equal if they have the same value.  Referring to [the documentation for `KeyValuePair`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3khwsc5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can see that the `Equals` method is inherited from `ValueType`, which performs as such when two values are compared.  This is important for key/value pairs because of the job that they perform, that is holding values with *unique* keys in a collection, and operations against these pairs make use of the `Equals` method under the hood when checking if there is already a key in the collection.

For instance, assume you have this struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public System.IO.Stream Value { get; set; }
}
```

The following will output "True":

```
var input = System.IO.File.OpenRead(myPath);
var myFirstStruct = new MyStruct();
var mySecondStruct = new MyStruct();
myFirstStruct.Value = input;
mySecondStruct.Value = input;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(myFirstStruct.Equals(mySecondStruct).ToString());
```

But if I have this class instead:

```
class MyClass
{
    public System.IO.Stream Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following will output "False":

```
var input = System.IO.File.OpenRead(myPath);
var myFirstClass = new MyClass();
var mySecondClass = new MyClass();
myFirstClass.Value = input;
mySecondClass.Value = input;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(myFirstClass.Equals(mySecondClass).ToString());
```

See the difference?  In the second example, the two instances are *not* equal because classes are reference types, not value types.

Comment: Both structs and classes can override their `Equals` methods.  They have different default implementations, but since the implementation can always be overridden, this is never a reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: @Servy -- Can you suggest how I can improve this answer?  Or do you think I'm totally off track?

Comment: Well, given the only reason you've given for choosing a struct over a class is never a reason to ever choose a struct over a class, I can't imagine how the answer could be fixed, beyond re-writing it entirely from scratch.

Comment: @Servy -- Okay, well I disagree with you.  I think this is a valid answer and reason to choose a stuct over a class unless you can substantiate your statement with a reference of some kind.

Comment: So you don't think that it's possible to override the `Equals` method of either a `struct` or a `class`?  You're really sticking with that one?  `public class Foo{override bool Equals(object other){return false;}}`  Done.

Comment: Of course it's possible, obviously.  If the struct or class does not override `Equals` -- which is the case with KeyValuePair -- then what I have said holds true.  At the very least, I would only need to modify my answer to include that.  However, that's quite different from saying it's "never a reason to ever choose a struct over a class", which is patently false.  You're really sticking with that one?

Comment: The statement that it needs to be a value type so that the `Equals` method will provide a value-based equality check is strictly false.  If a class was used the `Equals` method would need to be overridden, and you don't need to bother doing that (in this instance, although that's not always the case) here as the default value equality semantics are correct.  The fact that you would have to override equality for one and not the other should in no way influence your decision as to whether the type should be a value type or a reference type, I'm most certainly sticking with that statement.

Comment: I can assure you that MS didn't make this type a value type so that they wouldn't have to bother writing four lines of code to override the equality semantics.  They're going to make the decision based on the effects to end users (which are potentially dramatic) not just how many lines of code it would take to write.  Anyone who is making this decision based on that is almost certainly making a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Classes are reference types. Structs are value types. Makes sense semantically (and perhaps logically) that a value in a KeyValuePair would be accessible as a value type.